# VBA skipping to next none 0 cell in a row

Tags: excel, vba

I am in need of help trying to get this VBA macro work, I seem to be messing up with the ability to skip the cell's formula returning a 0 value and moving to the next available cell. In the sample image B1:B5 is good but once it hits B7 and B8 I'd like for it to instead return the next value into B9. The area I have quoted out is the area I am running into issues with.

```
    Sub AssignStow()
    Dim Worksheet As Worksheet
    Dim badgeID As String
    Dim cell As Integer
    Dim assignment As String
    Dim aname As String
    
    cell = 1
    
    Set Worksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Check In")
    badgeID = Worksheet.Range("scan")
    
    Set Worksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Stow")
    
    recheck:
    If IsEmpty(Worksheet.Cells(cell, 1)) = False Then
        cell = cell + 1
        GoTo recheck:
    End If
    
    If IsEmpty(Worksheet.Cells(cell, 1)) = True Then
        Worksheet.Cells(cell, 1).Value = badgeID

    For i = 1 To 75
        Do
            If assignment = "0" Then
                Worksheet.Cells(cell, 2).Value
                cell = cell + 1
            Else
                assignment = Worksheet.Cells(cell, 2).Value
                aname = Worksheet.Cells(cell, 3).Value
    
                GoTo display:
            End If
    Next i

    
    display:
    Set Worksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Check In")
    Worksheet.Range("scan").Value = ""
    If aname = "x" Then
        Worksheet.Range("badgeID").Value = badgeID
    Else
        Worksheet.Range("badgeID").Value = aname
    End If
    Worksheet.Cells(40, 1).Value = assignment
    
End Sub
```

[Image of excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXsXE.png)

Comment: What is the end result, to count the number of 0 or not?  (Also, I'd avoid the `GoTo` and for `GoTo display`, just use `Exit For` to get out of the `For` loop.  I'd change the other, where you have `GoTo recheck` to a `Do While` loop.)

Comment: This workbook is used to task people in at work, when I scan the badge on the main worksheet, it pulls the next available cell For the area of work they are in, once B1-5 are full it uses B6 but since that cell is pulling from a empty formula I’d like for it to move to the next none zero cell, Which in this case would be B9. Sorry if this still doesn’t explain it quite right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to prevent entering a badgeID next to a cell whose value is "0". Try like this:

```vb
Sub AssignStow()
    Dim Worksheet As Worksheet
    Dim badgeID As String
    Dim cell As Integer
    Dim assignment As String
    Dim aname As String
    
    cell = 1
    
    Set Worksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Check In")
    badgeID = Worksheet.Range("scan")
    
    Set Worksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Stow")
    
recheck:
    If IsEmpty(Worksheet.Cells(cell, 1)) = False Or Worksheet.Cells(cell, 2).Value = "0" Then
        cell = cell + 1
        GoTo recheck:
    End If
    
    If IsEmpty(Worksheet.Cells(cell, 1)) = True Then
        Worksheet.Cells(cell, 1).Value = badgeID
    End If

    If assignment = "0" Then
        cell = cell + 1
    Else
        assignment = Worksheet.Cells(cell, 2).Value
        aname = Worksheet.Cells(cell, 3).Value
        GoTo display
    End If
    
display:
    Set Worksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Check In")
    Worksheet.Range("scan").Value = ""
    If aname = "x" Then
        Worksheet.Range("badgeID").Value = badgeID
    Else
        Worksheet.Range("badgeID").Value = aname
    End If
    Worksheet.Cells(40, 1).Value = assignment
    
End Sub
```

To solve this, there needs to be a condition at the top of `recheck` which skips to the next row (increments the value of `cell`) if the value of the current cell in column B is "0". This is the same as when you are checking if the column A cell is empty, so it's been added there.

The `For` loop and the `Do` statement have been removed because they didn't seem to be doing anything.